# Spring data for neo4j 2.3 embedded mode

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am planning to use Neo4j 2.3 with Spring Data 3.x version with Neo4j in embedded mode. Is Spring data 3.x compatible with Neo4j 2.3? 
Ref: http://neo4j.com/blog/spring-data-neo4j-summer-update/
But this page was updated last on august 2015.

If it is compatible, will support continue for Spring Data 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Spring Data Neo4j 4.x - 3.x will not be supported/maintained going forward.